# Requesting Discord Attachments

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

**What I'm trying to do:**

*I'm trying to scrape all images in a discord channel and getting their URL by requesting attachments but I can't seem to find a way to request it*

**Code**

```
const fs = require("fs");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

function readFileString(path) {
  return fs.readFileSync(path, {encoding: "utf8"}).replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
}

const token = readFileString("token.txt");
const channel = process.argv[2];
if(!channel) {
  console.error("Usage: node index.js <channel id>");
  process.exit(1);
}

const headers = {authorization: token};

async function request(before) {
  const options = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: headers
    
  };
  
  const request = await fetch(
    `https://discord.com/api/channels/${channel}/attachments`, 
    options
  );
    
  return await request.json();
}

let result;

async function go() {
  let page = await request();
  
  result = page;

  while(page.length >= 100) {
    page = await request(page[page.length - 1].id);
    result = result.concat(page);
  }
  
  console.log(`Fetched ${result.length} images`);
  
  fs.writeFileSync("links.json", JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
}

go();
```

**Output: Console**

```
Fetched undefined images
```

**Output: `links.json`**

```
{
  "message": "404: Not Found",
  "code": 0
}
```

*Any help of how I would get all image links in the `links.json` file would be appreciated*

Answer (score 1):

It seems at looking at the [Docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) It does not allow you to make a `GET` request for message attachments.